# Spring Batch lower case table names

Tags: spring-batch

If you create the tables by Liquibase, is it possible to make the table names lower case? Or are there side effects and this is not a good recommendation?

```
# Done by Liquibase
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=never
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be a bad idea since the upper case table names are hard coded in spring batch.  For example the following is used in [JdbcJobExecutionDao](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/dao/JdbcJobExecutionDao.java)...

```java
    private static final String SAVE_JOB_EXECUTION = "INSERT into %PREFIX%JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JOB_INSTANCE_ID, START_TIME, "
            + "END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, VERSION, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    private static final String CHECK_JOB_EXECUTION_EXISTS = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %PREFIX%JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?";

    private static final String GET_STATUS = "SELECT STATUS from %PREFIX%JOB_EXECUTION where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?";
```

Comment: Thanks, for the link then yes upper case would be better